# How to remove Tailwind styles only in one vue component?

Tags: vue.js, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

I'm currently facing a situation where I need to remove the application-wide impact of the global Tailwind CSS framework, but only for a single specific component. This requirement stems from my desire to maintain an uncluttered and streamlined HTML document, devoid of any extraneous styling influences.

To tackle this, I'm eager to learn the most effective approach for achieving this objective. By isolating this particular component from the overarching styles, I hope to create a more focused and harmonious visual presentation within this specific context.

If you could graciously share your insights or steps on how I can implement this targeted removal of the global Tailwind CSS from just one component, I would greatly appreciate your guidance. Your assistance will undoubtedly contribute to the optimization of my project's aesthetics and structure.

Comment: This is the actual problem with global styles, don't use them if there's a chance this will backfire. Consider explaining your case, could be specific to it, e.g. shadow dom

Comment: The only plausible solution I can give you is to override the component style from within, although given the situation it's not very elegant. The global style unfortunately has this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure which areas of your codebase will use tailwind in your `tailwind.config.js` file's module.exports object under the "content" name.

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration

```js
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{html,js}',
    './components/**/*.{html,js}',
  ],
  // ...
}
```

As you can see above, the content uses a pattern matching method called globs (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming))

In glob programming, there are special wildcards you can use to ignore certain patterns by using the exclamation mark like `![the file you want to exclude]`.

I don't know your file structure but use this to your advantage to set up your `tailwind.config.js` to ignore that particular file.